# How to print rupee symbol in Windows console using Python?

Tags: python, unicode, symbols

I want to add the Indian Rupee Symbol to a program. This is a non GUI program  targeted at Windows and will be run as exe from console. (I would convert it to exe by pyinstaller in the end). I tried using:

```
print unicode(u"\u20B9")+"12,500"
```

(As taken from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm)
It works well in IDLE Interpreter but when I tried running the same code from cmd (Windows 7), it gave error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Programs\Projects\StockExchangeSim.py", line 9, in <module>
    print unicode(u"\u20B9")+"12,500"
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20b9' in position
 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a way to handle this? If there is, will it cause issues when used in other windows computers?

Answer (score 6):

```
raw_text = u"\u20B9"
print(raw_text)
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more?

Comment: Why does this work and not the original source code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would probably be to avoid trying to print Unicode characters to the windows console.  While it does [seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) it would appear to not be trivial to handle in all cases.

Might I suggest the simple solution of

```
print "12,500 Rupees"
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find that you question you linked because I searched thoroughly for rupee symbol only.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to print 'rupay' using python, we can use its respective unicode representation which is **'\u20B9'** . In order to Print rupay, we just have to do the following:

```
print(u'\u20B9')
```

And you will get 'rupay' symbol. It is irrespective of platform (as the question mentioned windows)